# Generate list of urls by comparing three urls

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to generate list of 20 urls by comparing three urls.

Example - 1: If I have three urls like:

```
http://www.test.com/asdf/1/lkjh
http://www.test.com/asdf/2/lkjh
http://www.test.com/asdf/3/lkjh
```

I want to find the difference among these three links and find the position of differentiating digit and generate many links like

```
http://www.test.com/asdf/1/lkjh
http://www.test.com/asdf/2/lkjh
http://www.test.com/asdf/3/lkjh
http://www.test.com/asdf/4/lkjh
http://www.test.com/asdf/5/lkjh
http://www.test.com/asdf/6/lkjh
http://www.test.com/asdf/7/lkjh
http://www.test.com/asdf/8/lkjh
http://www.test.com/asdf/9/lkjh
http://www.test.com/asdf/10/lkjh
http://www.test.com/asdf/11/lkjh
http://www.test.com/asdf/12/lkjh
http://www.test.com/asdf/13/lkjh
http://www.test.com/asdf/14/lkjh
http://www.test.com/asdf/15/lkjh
```

---

Example - 2: If I have three urls like:

```
http://www.test.com/asdf?qwer=1
http://www.test.com/asdf?qwer=2
http://www.test.com/asdf?qwer=3
```

I want to find the difference among these three links and find the position of differentiating digit and generate many links like

```
http://www.test.com/asdf?qwer=1
http://www.test.com/asdf?qwer=2
http://www.test.com/asdf?qwer=3
http://www.test.com/asdf?qwer=4
http://www.test.com/asdf?qwer=5
http://www.test.com/asdf?qwer=6
http://www.test.com/asdf?qwer=7
http://www.test.com/asdf?qwer=8
http://www.test.com/asdf?qwer=9
http://www.test.com/asdf?qwer=10
http://www.test.com/asdf?qwer=11
http://www.test.com/asdf?qwer=12
http://www.test.com/asdf?qwer=13
http://www.test.com/asdf?qwer=14
http://www.test.com/asdf?qwer=15
```

Please, let me know how to do this in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If the link only has one digit in, and you only care about adding 1 (as in your examples) you only need one link and can use something like this, where *base* is the starting URL and *n* is the number to create.

```
function generateLinks(base, n) {
  var result = [];
  result.push(base);
  for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    var newLink = base.replace(/\d+/, function(digit) { return Number(digit)+1 });
    result.push(newLink);
    base = newLink;
  }
  return result;
}
```